# subject-verb agreement with “a hundred”

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

Which is correct?

> 1. There **is** **a** hundred of people in the hall.

OR

> 2. There **are** a **hundred** of people in the hall.

*a hundred* means one hundred but determiner ‘a’ is singular. Which verb should be used, *is* or *are*?

Comment: "There are..." would be correct, but in many cases I have heard people say "There's a hundred people...", so don't be surprised if you hear that being used instead.

Comment: @TheIntern To clarify, *There's* + plural is acceptable **only informally**, and *\*There is* + plural is unacceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the formality and the speaker's level of excitement, I would not find either remarkable. "A hundred people" could easily be taken to be a synonym for "a crowd", in which case "is" would make grammatical sense.

"Are" is more generally applicable and more formally correct. If "a hundred" is an attempt to present a somewhat accurate count, then "are" is the only appropriate choice. But a speaker who was just trying to say "there's a crowd" might use "is", whether because she thinks of the hundred people as a unified mass, or by analogy with something like "There's a couple cans of soda in the fridge" or other [casual uses of measure words and counts as collective singulars](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27s%20a%20lot%20of%2Cthere%20are%20a%20lot%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20%27s%20a%20lot%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20lot%20of%3B%2Cc0). ["There's" to refer to counts of people is less common than "there are", but it has nontrivial representation, especially in recent times.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27s%20a%20hundred%20people%2Cthere%20are%20a%20hundred%20people&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20%27s%20a%20hundred%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20hundred%20people%3B%2Cc0)

So which one a person would say depends on what the person is thinking about and how carefully he or she is monitoring his or her speech. What you see "in the wild" is not necessarily what is formally grammatically correct.

However, I would point out that the biggest sign of non-native speech occurs in both your examples: we use "a hundred" as a quantity, not as a measure word, so "a hundred **of** people" would seem wrong to me. We'd just say "a hundred people." (A [measure word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_word), on the other hand, is something like "pair" in "pair of pants" or "head" in "head of cattle"--there it represents a basic unit of counting which must always be used to count the object in question.) So might say "a lot of people" but never "*a hundred of people".